# how to extract CountryData[] without String names for use in numeric analysis

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, code-request

I have the following `Code` that extracts selected variables and makes a table. I like to use these data in statistical analysis such as `Fit[...]`, but I cannot use them because `String` variable units are also extracted together with the raw data.

How can I extract the raw data without `String` units and export it as an `XLS` file for use in Linear and Nonlinear Regression analysis?

```
countLst={"Argentina", "Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", 
  "Bulgaria","Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Canada",  
  "Switzerland", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", 
  "Cyprus", "Czech Republic","Germany", "Denmark", "Spain", 
  "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "United Kingdom", "Greece", 
  "Hong Kong", "Croatia", "Hungary", "Indonesia", "India", 
  "Ireland", "Iceland", "Israel", "Italy", "Japan", "Kazakhstan",
  "Cambodia", "South Korea", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Latvia", 
  "Morocco", "Mexico", "Malta", "Malaysia", "Netherlands", 
  "Norway", "New Zealand", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", 
  "Portugal", "Romania", "Russian Federation", "Saudi Arabia", 
  "Singapore", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Sweden", 
  "Thailand", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Taiwan", "United States", 
  "Vietnam", "South Africa"
 };

Text[Grid[
  Prepend[{CountryData[#, "Name"],
  CountryData[#,"PopulationGrowth"],
  CountryData[#, "GDP"],
  CountryData[#, "TotalFertilityRate"], 
  CountryData[#, "GrossInvestment"], 
  CountryData[#, "InternetUsers"], 
  CountryData[#, "InventoryChange"], 
  CountryData[#, "MedianAge"], 
  CountryData[#, "TradeValueAdded"], 
  CountryData[#, "UnemploymentFraction"]} & /@ countLst, {"", 
  "pop. growth", "GDP", "fertility", "grossInv", "internet", 
  "inventory", "medianAge", "tradeVA", "unempl."}], Frame -> All, 
  Background -> {None, {LightBlue, {LightYellow}}}]
 ]
```

Comment: If I understand the question correcty then this is not a minimal example. If the question is "how do I get the numeric value of f.e. `CountryData["Sweden", "GDP"]` without the unit", then the answer is `QuantityMagnitude@CountryData["Sweden", "GDP"]` and that's the approach one should use for all properties.

Comment: @C.E: Thank you for your suggestion. I used it to answer my own question. I think I succeded in what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A streamlined way to construct the desired rectangular table using [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html):

```
countryList = (SeedRandom[777]; RandomSample[countLst, 20]);

propList = {"Name", "PopulationGrowth", "GDP", "TotalFertilityRate", 
  "GrossInvestment", "MedianAge"}; 

propLabels = {"country", "pop. growth", "GDP", "fertility", "grossInv", "medianAge"};

table = Prepend[propLabels] @ Select[FreeQ[_Missing]] @ ReplaceAll[Quantity -> (# &)] @
     Outer[CountryData, countryList, propList];

Grid @ table
```

[image]

You might also consider `Dataset`:

```
ds = Dataset @ Select[FreeQ[_Missing]] @ AssociationThread[countryList, 
    Map[AssociationThread[propList,
      Function[p, ReplaceAll[Quantity -> (# &)] @ 
       CountryData[#, p]] /@ propList] &] @ countryList]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the `Dataset` code, which is compact and user friendly. Thanks for the code.

Comment: In `Dataset` option, would it be possible to Alphabetically sort the data with country names?

Comment: just use `Sort[ds]` or `KeySort[ds]` or `SortBy[#Name &][ds]`. The latter is a convenient syntax to sort by arbitrary columns; e.g., `SortBy[#GDP &][ds]`.

Answer (score 1):

Following @C.E's suggestion, I retrieved selected variables without strings:

```
Text[Grid[
   Prepend[data = {CountryData[#, "Name"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#,    "PopulationGrowth"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "GDP"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "TotalFertilityRate"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "GrossInvestment"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "InternetUsers"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "InventoryChange"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "MedianAge"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "TradeValueAdded"], 
   QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "UnemploymentFraction"]} & /@ 
 countLst, {"", "pop. growth", "GDP", "fertility", "grossInv", 
"internet", "inventory", "medianAge", "tradeVA", "unempl."}],
Frame -> All, Background -> {None, {LightBlue, {LightYellow}}}]]
```

Then, I deleted `Missing` observations from `data`:

```
(*Export "data" to XLS format after deleting "Missing" observations*)

dataClean = Take[Select[data, FreeQ[#, _Missing] &], All, All];  (* thanks to @kglr *)
Export["(*directory address to save the Exported data*)\\dataClean.xls", dataClean];
```

Then I run two regression estimations (linear and quadratic) and plot original data points together with the regression lines:

```
(*Use a subset of "data" to run "Fit[...]" over "ListPlot[...]"*)

ClearAll[data, line, parabola];
data = {QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "PopulationGrowth"],      QuantityMagnitude@CountryData[#, "GDP"]}&/@countLst;
line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x];
parabola = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2}, x];
Show[
 ListPlot[data, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], Plot[{line, parabola}, {x, 0, 15}]
 ]
```

In summary, here is what I did with this `Code`:

1. Extract data from `CountryData[]` without any strings
2. Delete `Missing` observations from the extracted data set
3. Export the clean data set to an external `XLS` file
4. Run two types of regressions using the clean data
5. Plot the original data points together with the Regression functions
6. Here is I produced:

[image]